# Does CakePHP DebugKit have built-in support for changing the toolbar location?

Tags: cakephp

I'm enjoying using CakePHP's DebugKit toolbar, but is there a simple way to change its location from top right to anywhere else on the screen without having to fiddle with the code?

If the answer to this question were as simple as changing the CSS from top:0px; to bottom:0px; for #debug-toolkit-bar, I'd have already done it and I wouldn't be asking a question in the first place.  The answer definitely isn't documented in the ever-so-hefty 9k readme.md file found on github unless you're referring to the section on **Toolbar Configuration Settings**:

> The toolbar has a few configuration settings. Settings are passed in
>   the component declaration like normal component configuration.
>
> public $components = array(
>       'DebugKit.Toolbar' => array(/* array of settings */) );

That's all it says about the "array of settings" - not much help there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not have built-in support for changing it's location.

> **OP:** If the answer to this question were as simple as changing the CSS from
>   top:0px; to bottom:0px; for #debug-toolkit-bar, I'd have already done
>   it and I wouldn't be asking a question in the first place.

It is actually that simple.  To change it's location, just look at the CSS for the `debug-kit-toolbar` and the `panel-tabs` and override the `float-left`s to right and the position to left instead of right...etc - all simple CSS stuff.

As far as the settings, you can view any/all of it's settings by looking at [the code for the DebugKit Toolbar in Github](https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit/blob/master/Controller/Component/ToolbarComponent.php).

Comment: Thanks Dave - I had already moved the toolbar a bit lower on the page, but it continues to get in the way and putting it at the bottom causes the contents to open under the toolbar (off the screen).  Before I went and spent the time to edit the CSS (a skill I'm not very strong at) I was hoping someone would tell me it's as easy as DebugKit::toolbar(array('location'=>'bottom-right')); or something similar.

Comment: One thing we've done in the past (also helps with page-load times) is to require ?debug=1 for debug to be on.  For early development, it's not great, because you often need the debug ON, but - for later, it's nice to work on it, then IF you need to see debugKit (or have debug on for another reason), then you can just slap ?debug=1 on the url, and voila.

Comment: Spotted that in the docs - I plan on wrapping access to using that feature in a permission and deploying debugkit with the first few production versions.  I'm just not to that point yet.

Comment: @user1615499 - just MAKE SURE not to ONLY use the ?debug=1 url as the thing to turn it on - add some IP filtering or something as well.